# Django - User CeleryBeat in Production with Supervisor

Tags: python, django, supervisord, celerybeat

An example celerybeat conf file looks like this

```
[program:celerybeat]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=celery beat -A myapp --schedule /var/lib/celery/beat.db --loglevel=INFO

; remove the -A myapp argument if you are not using an app instance

directory=/path/to/project
user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=999
```

How would I use celerybeat to schedule the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {}` in my django settings file.  What would I change `--schedule /var/lib/celery/beat.db` to?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=celerybeat_scheduler#celerybeat-schedule-filename) well you have to write

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE_FILENAME = '/var/lib/celery/beat.db'
```

Comment: Would I replace FILENAME with say settings, since my CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE is in my settings.py file?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure to understand your question. In settings.py you use `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` to define your schedule (see [Entries](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries) in the doc).

`CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE_FILENAME` is something else, it defines "the file used by PersistentScheduler to store the last run times of periodic tasks". Do you use the PersistentScheduler or another one ?